# How to cancel Google for Work billing? There's no way to contact them

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I'm from Brazil, and I had a Google Apps account with a domain. After I deleted it, I'm still being charged on my credit card, and there's no way to cancel or contact Google!

The e-mail says:

> To review or make changes to your billing details, please visit your
>   account. Here's how:
>
> **1. Sign in to your Google for Work Admin Console**.
>
> 2. Click on 'Billing'.
> 3. Click on the overflow menu (three vertical dots) on the right hand
>      side of your  Google for Work subscription.
> 4. Click on 'Access billing account'.
>
> If you don't see the Billing Info section in the Admin console, you
>   might need to sign in with appropriate billing admin credentials. If
>   you have any questions, visit our Help Center.
>
> See you online,  The Google Billing Team

The first step won't work, because I don't have a Google for Work account.

If I try to login with my account, I'm redirected to the same page asking me for my Google for Work account...
https://admin.google.com/accountchooser?consumerAccountUsed=true

If I try the help center, I keep in loop on the pages trying to send a message to them...

Does anyone experienced this? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would give Google Apps for Work support a phone call and tell them the situation.  Here is a link to the world wide phone numbers for Google Apps for Work.

https://support.google.com/a/table/3247295?hl=en

There is a number for Brazil in there.